# Swift UI and PDFKit - How do I update my page programmatically?

Tags: swiftui, pdfkit

I want to update the view when the State of currentpage changes by a button.
In console the tap make current page increase accordingly.

I tried with gotoNextPage() (SOLUTION 2)and it is not working
and also tried with go to method.(SOLUTION 1)
Non of them are updating even if printed values seems to be ok.

```
PDFVIEW CurrentPage value is:Optional(<PDFPage: 0x281917b60> page index 203)
```

Any solution, please?

```
@State var pdfName: String
@State var start: Int

PDFKitView(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: pdfName, withExtension: "pdf")!, currentPage: start)
```

```
import SwiftUI  
import PDFKit

struct PDFKitView: View {
    var url: URL
    var currentPage: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        PDFKitRepresentedView(url, currentPage)
    }
}

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    let currentPage: Int
    let pdfView = PDFView()

    init(_ url: URL, _ currentPage: Int) {
        self.url = url
        self.currentPage = currentPage
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        print("PDFVIEW IS CREATED")
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
        pdfView.go(to: pdfView.document!.page(at: currentPage)!)
        
        let total = pdfView.document?.pageCount
        print("Total pages: \(total ?? 0)")
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        // Update the view.
             
        //THIS IS PRINTED IN CONSOLE EVERY TIME  
        print("PDFVIEW IS UPDATED")
        print("CurrentPage value is:\(currentPage)")
        
        //SOLUTION TRIED 1. SAME CODE WORKS ON makeUIView: I can see the pdf, scroll it     and zoom. Also let it start at any page I want to. But not here.
        print("PDFVIEW IS UPDATED")
        print("CurrentPage value is:\(currentPage)")
        
        //SOLUTION 1
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
        pdfView.go(to: pdfView.document!.page(at: currentPage)!)
        print("PDFVIEW CurrentPage value is:\(pdfView.currentPage)")

        /*

        PDFVIEW IS UPDATED
        CurrentPage value is:203
        PDFVIEW CurrentPage value is:Optional(<PDFPage: 0x281917b60> page index 203)
        */
      
        //SOLUTION TRIED 2
        //goToNextPage()
    }
    
    func goToNextPage(){
        pdfView.goToNextPage(nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of truth should be somewhere outside and injected by binding or other observable type inside.

Here is simplified fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Main part:

```
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        guard let document = PDFDocument(url: self.url) else { return UIView() }

        let pdfView = PDFView()
        print("PDFVIEW IS CREATED")
        pdfView.document = document
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.total = document.pageCount
            print("Total pages: \(total)")
        }
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        guard let pdfView = uiView as? PDFView else { return }

        if currentPage < total {
            pdfView.go(to: pdfView.document!.page(at: currentPage)!)
        }
    }
```

*Note: handling `PDFView` delegate navigation by swipe to pass back in binding is on you.*

[Complete test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestPDFViewNavigation.swift)